# Coordinates of framed text on an image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I would like to get the coordinates of framed text on an image. The paragraphs have thin black borders. The rest of the image contains usual paragraphs and sketchs.

Here is an example: [image]

Do you have any idea of what kind of algorithms should I use in Python with an image library to achieve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas to detect a framed text which largely comes down to searching boxes/rectangles of substantial size:

- find contours with OpenCV, analyze shapes using [`cv2.approxPolyDP()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#contour-approximation) *polygon approximation algorithm* (also known as [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)). You could additionally check the aspect ratio of the bounding box to make sure the shape is a rectangle as well as check the page width as this seems to be a known metric in your case. PyImageSearch did this amazing article:

  - [OpenCV shape detection](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/)
- in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57196047/how-to-detect-all-the-rectangular-boxes-in-the-given-image), there is also a suggestion to look into [Hough Lines](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) to detect a horizontal line, taking a turn a detecting vertical lines the same way. Not 100% sure how reliable this approach would be.

---

Once you find the box frames, the next step would be to check if there is any text inside them. Detecting text is a broader problem in general and there are many ways of doing it, here are a few examples:

- apply [EAST text detector](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/)
- [PixelLink](https://github.com/ZJULearning/pixel_link)
- [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/) (e.g. via `pytesseract`) but not sure if this would not have too many false positives
- if it is a simpler case of boxes being empty or not, you could check for average pixel values inside - e.g. with [`cv2.countNonZero()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero). Examples:

  - [How to identify empty rectangle using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53719807)
  - [Count the black pixels using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19167645)

---

Additional references:

- [ideas on quadrangle/rectangle detection using convolutional neural networks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44308660/771848)

Comment: But even after detecting rectangles, you would need to verify if there is text inside them right? What if there are rectangles with blank areas? I think you would need to do some sort of OCR detection inside the rectangular patches afterwards.

Comment: @Ananda good points. I was initially thinking of tesseract for the filtered-out rectangular contours but that would probably lead to false positives. I think EAST would work - added some info to the answer. Thanks.